# Why does ${z$i}=$line result in a "bad substitution" error?

Tags: bash

i need to use a variable composed from the name of another variable

```
#!/bin/bash -x

i=0
cat << EOF | while read -r line
a
b
c
d
EOF
do
    ((i++))
    ${z$i}=$line
done
```

but is not working, i get "bad substitution"

so, how can i do something like that ?

Comment: Since @dirkgently solved your issue, please don't forget to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there isn't a particular reason to stick to `z1`, `z2` etc. I'd recommend using [Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) instead.